# react Regex for value after colon in dom

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test for the presence of text after a certain value in my html document:

```
<span>Dog facts: something</span>
```

I want to test for the presence of text after the pattern "Dog facts:" to not be null

It should be noted the value after Dog facts: changes so I can't assert on a specific value I just need to make sure that there exists text after the colon.

I am not sure if regex is what I want but I tried doing this:

```
test('renders dog facts', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/Dog facts:/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

but this always returns true no matter whats after the colon

Comment: Add `.+`, it matches one or more chars. Or, `\s*\S` to make sure there is at least one non-whitespace char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only match for a letter after the dog facts you can use this.

```
/Dog Facts: \w/g
```